# How to set more time for session and creating label to select more time from user end?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

I am a learner, i was wonder when i see a application in my office.. Web application with authentication and session time out as well, which is same as like all other applications.  But there is one label or link option called "need more time or more time is required for session" and this option is for end user.. If we click on that link it will give some more extra time for your session. Can you guys just help me out how to write code for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set session timeout to some value say 30 minutes. Use javascript code to detect user inactivity or idle time.

[Detecting Idle Time](http://paulirish.com/2009/jquery-idletimer-plugin/)

If the user is inactive for say 20 minutes, you can show him the popup or link to the user saying do you want to continue your session. If the user click the link his session will continue, otherwise he will be redirected to logout page.